# Combine two sources of friends relationships in one table

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have mobile app with users. Everything is simple - each user have *id* and *name*.

**Users Table**

```
id name 
1  John
2  Dave 
3  Jack
```

Some of this users are friends and the main purpose of my question - finding the best way to rebuild friendship table that looks like (the only rule is user_id_1 < user_id_2)

**Friendship table**

```
id user_1_id user_2_id 
1  1         2
2  1         3 
3  2         3
```

How I know that users are friends? I take this information from different sources (social network A, social network B). **So if two users are friends at least in one of two social networks - they are friends in my app**.

Right now I am recreating friendship table each day:

1. Take each user, create empty array NewFriends for this user
2. Erase all records containing his id from friendship table
3. Find all his friends in network A (*A-friends*)
4. For each of *A-friends* - find they ids in my app and add them to NewFriends array
5. Find all his friends in network B (*B-friends*)
6. For each of *B-friends* - find they ids in my app and add them to NewFriends array if they don't already exist there
7. Delete all friendship records from Friendship table that are not mentioned in NewFriends array
8. Insert all friendship records from NewFriends array to Friendship table that were not existed there before

How can I solve this task better?

Answer (score 1):

First,
you can use the only one table of the 2 networks (instead of using  A-friends table and  B-friends table)
and when select you could use distinct keyword
steps will be :

1. Take each user
2. Erase all records containing his id from friendship table
3. Find all his friends in network A and add it to (Temp-friends)
4. Find all his friends in network B and add it to (Temp-friends)
5. For each distinct  of Temp-friends - add records in NewFriends table
6. Delete all friendship records from Friendship table that are not mentioned in NewFriends array
7. Insert all friendship records from NewFriends array to Friendship table that were not existed there before

Answer (score 1):

You can use set data type instead array. The reason to use set is set doesn't contain duplicate values.

Use two sets `oldFriendships` and `newFriendships`.

1. From friendships table load data to `oldFriendships`
2. Create new `newFriendships`
   2.1. From network **A** find all friends for the user and add it to the `newFriendships`
   2.2. From network **B** find all friends for the user and add it to the `newFrindships`
3. Update friendship table
   3.1 Find `oldFriendships` complement `newFrindships` - this is removed friendships, delete these values from friendship table
   3.2. Find `newFrindships` complement `oldFriendships` - this is added friendships, add these values to friendship table

Here is [wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) article about complement